# Comentários em JSON no Visual Studio

Tags: json, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

O JSON não suporta comentários, porém no Visual Studio (2017 pra ser mais específico, minha versão) eu adiciono comentários e não me apresenta nenhum erro, porém quando eu abro o arquivo no Visual Studio **Code**, a seguinte mensagem me é apresentada: **Comments are not permitted in JSON.**

Alguem sabe me explicar isso?

Comment: No VSCode também é possível usar comentários no JSON. Acredito que deve ter alguma coisa nativa de cada sistema em particular que Minifyca(compila/decompila) o JSON quando vc salva/abre o arquivo. Da uma olhada nesse link que tem um vídeo interessante. https://www.oreilly.com/learning/adding-comments-in-json no StackOverflow gringo tb tem bastante coisa sobre o assunto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-comments-be-used-in-json e aqui é o projeto do VSCode no GitHub https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode

Comment: @hugocsl viu que no final do video o autor coloca uma pergunta legal no <title>, Can you use comments in json? Acho que isso merece uma discussão mehor já que é uma arranjo!

Answer (score 1):

O parser JSON padrão do VS Code não suporta comentários, porém ele tem outro disponível que suporta.

Você pode simplesmente escolher esse outro parser, para um arquivo em particular, através dos seguintes passos:

1. Clique na barra de status, no item que indica o formato do arquivo `JSON`.
2. Escolha o parser `JSON with Comments (jsonc)`
3. Pronto

Ou então, você pode configurar para que o VS Code sempre use esse parser quando abrir um arquivo `.json`. Para isso, siga os seguintes passos:

1. Clique na barra de status, no item que indica o formato do arquivo `JSON`.
2. Escolha a opção `Configure File Association for ‘.json’...`
3. Escolha o parser `JSON with Comments`
4. Pronto

A partir desse momento, toda vez que você abrir um arquivo `.json`, será usado o parser que suporta comentários.

Answer (score 0):

Em JSON, se você incluir um comentário ele será tambem um dado;

Em seu arquivo JSON, você poderia criar um comentário  dessa formar;

```
"_comentario" : "seu comentario",
```

E você pode ignorar o valor quando for usar em seu aplicativo;

Porque foi definido dessa formar pela  [Standard ECMA - 404, 2a Edição - Dezembro - 2017](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf),

Que um Objeto JSON começa com chave "{" de abertura e termina com chave "}" de fechamento. Cada nome é seguido por : (dois pontos) e os pares nome/valor são seguidos por , (vírgula).

Veja mais informação no link abaixo:

https://www.json.org/json-pt